# GitHub action workflow schedule not working on non-default branch

Tags: git, git-branch, github-actions

I am trying to setup a workflow on a branch called `workflow-test`. It has to run on a schedule and run every 24 hours. This workflow has to run a python script and commit and push the changes made by the python script. I got it to work on pushes, but it doesn't seem to work on schedules. I have looked at every question regarding this topic and tried all solutions, but to no avail.

This is my code:

```
name: update-state
on: 
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: workflow-test

      - name: Setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
      - name: Execute script
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          python scripts/script.py
        
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add -A
          git commit -m "update data" -a
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@v0.6.0
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: workflow-test
```

This is what I have tried:

- Run a schedule on the master branch, which should trigger the schedule to work on the other branch, according to a stack overflow answer;
- Add the `with: ref: branch`-part.

I have also tried just triggering this workflow on a push, which did work. Everything ran and worked. This was without the `with: ref: branch`-part. But from what I understand that is necessary when working with a schedule because schedule checks out to the last commit of the default branch, thus it has to be changed to the branch you are working on.

It doesn't seem to even attempt to run this workflow. It gives no record of attempting to run this workflow under the "actions" tab. Thus, I believe the problem lies with the `schedule` part, since it works on push and doesn't even run when working on a schedule.

I have also tried adding a simple workflow on schedule to my `master` branch, which does run. But when I add this simple workflow on schedule to my `workflow-test` branch, it doesn't run anymore.

I can't find anymore fixes on stack overflow, documentation or anywhere else. Thus I decided to open my own question. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance :).

Edit: this workflow updates the data used by a website.

Comment: Is the workflow file committed to the master branch?

Comment: It doesn't work in a non-default branch for me either. Looks like the documentation is lacking in this regard.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Scheduled GitHub Actions run on the default or base branch, as specified by [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule):

> Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or
> base branch.

Which means that your workflow file must be committed to the `master` or `main` branch. It then can check out code from other branches, but the workflow file itself must reside in the branch that is designated the default branch.

Here is the most minimal example that demonstrates how it works.

```yaml
name: Experiment
on: 
  schedule:
  - cron: '*/5 * * * *'

jobs:
  job1:
    name: Debug
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Git checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with: { ref: debug }
    - name: List files
      run: ls
```

This action runs every 5 minutes (`*/5`) and lists the files in the `debug` branch.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you very much for your solution. However, the documentation seems to be quite lacking then. No where in the documentation does it clearly state that scheduled workflows must reside in the `master` branch. Also no other solutions (out of what I could find) mentioned this solution.

Comment: Yes. GitHub sometimes refers to the `master` branch as the "default branch", since it may be something other than `master` for some people.